# Vertical line inside a <View> tag is not visible for the childs inside the RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml

[image]> [image: Blockquote]

I am facing a weird issue where the **View** tag visibility is automatically gone for the children inside the recycler view. I have used the View tag to draw a verticle line. However, the verticle line in the preview tab during compile time inside Android Studio is visible but when I run the project it does not appear.

My layout for the Recycler view adapter is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/atvCalendarDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Day 0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llImageContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/aivDay"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/solid_circle_bg" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clSprayingContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_crop_caledar_info_bg"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_15dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_15dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clMajorGrowthStage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/clSprayingStage"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/aivMajorGrowthStage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_satellite_off"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/atvMajorGrowthStage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_satellite_off"
                android:text="ffkhfkjhgjhkhjkvhhjhvhkvhvkhvkhh"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/aivMajorGrowthStage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clSprayingStage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/clMajorGrowthStage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/aivSprayingStage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_satellite_off"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/atvSprayingStage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_satellite_off"
                android:text="@string/seed_variety"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/aivSprayingStage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show the output of the ui when u run the app in your device. How it looks like...

Comment: I have added the output of the UI please have a look

Comment: Try changing the height of llImageContainer to match_parent, generally i recommend you rebuild your layout into constraintLayout instead of LinearLayout

Comment: Thanks @MuhannadFakhouri that worked for me. If I had to make that line a dotted line how can I do it?

Comment: You can set the background to be a shape drawable like this one `<shape>
        <stroke android:dashGap="2dp" android:dashWidth="2dp" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>`